# django oscar rebuild_index with error

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-oscar

> `apps.search.search_indexes.py`

```
class ProductIndex(search_indexes.ProductIndex):

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return super(ProductIndex, self).index_queryset().exclude(categories=None)

    def read_queryset(self, using=None):
        return super(ProductIndex, self).read_queryset().exclude(categories=None)

    def prepare(self, obj):
        prepared_data = super(ProductIndex, self).prepare(obj)    
        attrs = defaultdict(set)

        attrs_from_obj = lambda obj: [attrs[attr.attribute.code].add(attr.value) for attr in obj.attr.get_values()]

        if obj.is_parent:
            for child in obj.children.all():
                attrs_from_obj(child)
        else:
            attrs_from_obj(obj)

        for attr, vals in attrs.items():
            prepared_data[attr] = list(vals)

        return prepared_data
```

`./manage_py rebuild_indexes --noinput`
After that i have an error:

> Failed to add documents to Solr: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=catalogue.product.1451] unknown field 'proizvoditel']

in dashboard i have product type with attribute named `Producer` with code `proizvoditel`

I replaced `proizvoditel` -> `proizvoditel_s` and rebuild_index is ok, but search not works.

Comment: could you show the relevant code like models, views etc

Comment: add more details so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an unknown field error it's probably due to a field you're trying to introduce that's not yet registered in the schema.

What version of Django-Oscar and Solr are you using? I'm using Oscar 1.5 with Solr 4.7.2, so there might be a slight variation with your setup.

If you run the following (assuming you're following the Oscar docs) in bash it should resolve your field problem:

```
$ python manage.py build_solr_schema > solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
```

If you have your own Solr setup, then run `build_solr_scema` by itself and copy the file into your solr's conf directory.

Make sure you restart the server. Then do:

```
$ python manage.py rebuild_index --noinput
```

See if that helps.